# Hibernate how to use order by clause for sort by sum of field

Tags: hibernate, orm, hql, criteria, criteria-api

How to use order by clause for sort by sum of field

**Entity:**

```
    class MyClass {

        private int a;
        private int b;

        //...

    }
```

HQL works correctly:

**"SELECT myclass FROM MyClass myclass ORDER BY myclass.a + myclass.b DESC "**

How to do the same thing using Criteria API?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way without hacking your own Order subclass that would override toSqlString(). Why don't you keep it as a HQL query?

Comment: Is true? My HQL works. "Hibernate doesn't support arithmetics expressions in the order by clause."  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2373359/1319419

Comment: Well, things have probably changed since 2010, since your HQL query works fine.

Comment: How about use @Formula for this case?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You said that your HQL query did work fine. Why not use it then?

Comment: I dont know :) I everywhere use the Criteria API, uniform style.

Comment: The Criteria API is much more limitating than HQL, and leads to longer, harder to read code. It's useful when dynamic queries must be created (like for a search form with multiple optional criteria). Other than that, HQL is much easier, more maintainable, and more powerful. Use it.

Comment: You have a point there.

Comment: @JBNizet Very true. And for the same reasons, I first decided to use Criteria but later ended up using a mixture of HQL & Criteria at places according to requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you could use `@Formula`

```
@Column(name="column_a")
private Integer a;
@Column(name="column_b")
private Integer b;
@Formula("(column_a+column_b)")
private Integer c;
```

After that you can sort by property `c` like

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("c"));
```