# Sort records on sum of multiple columns with the Hibernate Criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

```
ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.property("request.requestId"));
projList.add(Projections.property("request.createdDate"));
projList.add(Projections.property("request.tripType"));
projList.add(Projections.property("request.origin"));
projList.add(Projections.property("request.destination"));
projList.add(Projections.property("request.noOfAdult"));
projList.add(Projections.property("request.noOfChild"));
projList.add(Projections.property("request.noOfInfant"));
projList.add(Projections.property("request.requestStatus"));
projList.add(Projections.property("request.paymentStatus"));
projList.add(Projections.property("request.totalFare"));
projList.add(Projections.property("request.lastUpdatedDate"));
projList.add(Projections.property("request.total"));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projList));

criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("request.totalCount"));
```

Now I want to sort those records based on the sum of request.noOfAdult,request.noOfChild,request.noOfInfant.

If I need to sort on any one field then I can do criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("request.noOfAdult")), but I need to do on the sum of that three fields..

How I can achieve this functionality?

POJO

```
package com.tsal.grms.dao.hibernate.entities;
// Generated Nov 10, 2016 6:30:12 PM by Hibernate Tools 5.2.0.Beta1

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Formula;

/**
 * GrmsRequestInfo generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
public class GrmsRequestInfo implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */

    @Column(name="NO_OF_ADULT")
    private Integer noOfAdult;
    @Column(name="NO_OF_CHILD")
    private Integer noOfChild;
    @Column(name="NO_OF_INAFNT")
    private Integer noOfInfant;

    @Formula("(NO_OF_ADULT+NO_OF_CHILD+NO_OF_INAFNT)")
    private Integer totalCount;


    public Integer getTotalCount() {
        return totalCount;
    }

    public void setTotalCount(Integer totalCount) {
        this.totalCount = totalCount;
    }

}
```

Exception

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: totalCount of: com.tsal.grms.dao.hibernate.entities.GrmsRequestInfo
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassPropertyTableNumber(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1995) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1970) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:518) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumnsUsingProjection(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:482) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.criterion.Order.toSqlString(Order.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getOrderBy(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1663) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at com.tsal.grms.dao.requestdao.SearchRequestDaoImpl.searchRequestDetails(SearchRequestDaoImpl.java:287) [com-tsal-grms-dao-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) [spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.searchRequestDetails(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at com.tsal.grms.dao.client.RequestManagementDaoClientImpl.searchRequestDetails(RequestManagementDaoClientImpl.java:44) [com-tsal-grms-dao-client-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.tsal.grms.core.requestmanagement.RequestManagementCoreImpl.searchRequestDetails(RequestManagementCoreImpl.java:93) [com-tsal-grms-core-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.tsal.grms.core.client.requestmanagment.RequestManagementCoreClientImpl.searchRequestDetails(RequestManagementCoreClientImpl.java:22) [com-tsal-grms-core-client-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.tsal.grms.api.SearchRequestController.searchRequests(SearchRequestController.java:85) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.tsal.grms.api.auth.filter.ExtendTokenFilter.doFilter(ExtendTokenFilter.java:94) [classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:131) [spring-security-oauth2-1.0.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_102]
```

Comment: Try with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742072/hibernate-how-to-use-order-by-clause-for-sort-by-sum-of-field and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898926/using-sum-and-arithmetic-result-as-order-key-in-hibernate-criteria

Comment: Tried, but while adding c variable to Order.asc("c") getting error
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: c of: hibernate entity

Comment: Add entire exception stack and POJO file details

Comment: Solved. In my hibernate mapping xml file I have added 
<property name="totalCount" type="java.lang.Integer" 
           formula="(NO_OF_ADULT+NO_OF_CHILD)" />
I have one file for hibernate mapping, so not require to use any annotation in the POJO class, only totalCount varaible should be there.