# JPA @OrderBy Annotation - Ordering Strings

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, sql-order-by

I am using the @OrderBy annotation in my entity class to sort a collection that is eagerly fetched. The column I am ordering on is of type String. However, in some instances, these strings may contain numbers. How do I ensure that the OrderBy annotation will order numbers stored as strings in their numeric order instead of 1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ?

Answer (score 1):

`@OrderBy` will sort according to the database since it will be part of your SQL query. Using [@SortComparator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/SortComparator.html) with a custom comparator will achieve your result. You can also consider combining the 2 as well (@OrderBy so that you return in some consistent order from the database, then the @SortComparator for the desired order)

Not sure if you have an idea of how to write the comparator, but  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number) is a start to that.

Comment: Where `@SortComparable` come from?

Comment: Typo, it's meant to be @SortComparator .. updating my answer for this

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider storing the strings as 0-prefix to a fixed maximum length, eg: 001, 023, 234 etc.   Ordering will then work correctly using the normal string alpha comparison.

See [Ordering results by computed value in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370215/ordering-results-by-computed-value-in-hibernate) for a JPA specific implementation way of achiveing close to the same thing.

Another option is to store your collection in a TreeSet with a custom comparator.